# Distibuted Cache in Reduce Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I want to hold File A in the memory of reducer1 and File B in the memory of reducer2. Is this possible using Distributed Cache technology in hadoop? Or else, is there any other way to acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if the files are considerably small you can set these files in distributed cache.
Follow this link http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata. It might be useful to u.

And if you consider this portion of the code its up to u which file u want to work upon in which reducer.

```
Path [] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
      if (null != cacheFiles && cacheFiles.length > 0) {
        for (Path cachePath : cacheFiles) {
          if (cachePath.getName().equals(stopwordCacheName)) {
            loadStopWords(cachePath);
            break;
          }
        }
```

See if it helps

Comment: Thanks, it helps, will implement it and get back to you!

Comment: Hi, I want to add the file which has the same name as the key of the reducer. But the above code, I implement it in the configure method of the reducer class, which is called before the reduce method. I don't know how to read the file which has the same name as the key of reducer. Pls help!

Comment: How many files are there that u r trying to put in distributed cache?
If the size is small, load it in a Hashmap with the Key and value as the record of the file depending on the type of your file.

Comment: There is going to a lot of such files, it can scale from 100s to even several 1000s .. each file corresponds to the key of the reducer... But when I try to read a specific file using the above technique, I do it in the configure method before the reduce method. But I can't access the reduce method keys in the configure method.. don't know how to proceed. I think I cannot put in a hashmap, as the  no of files is large. Any ideas?

Comment: Couldu please give me the detail of your use case? Are the keys used as the name of the file? Or u have to do with the contents? I am not sure. 
I will try to help here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem (and it is a fundamental problem w/Hadoop) is that task tracker launches new JVM process for each task - negating any benefit of in-memory caching. You can configure task tracker to run in the same VM - but many Hadoop internal use System.exit() and so many Hadoop jobs too... making such configuration pointless.

You can co-deploy GridGain cluster along with Hadoop cluster and use GridGain for in-memory caching via quick loopback connectivity between two JVMs on the same physical host (GridGain and Hadoop's task tracker JVMs that is) - something that is done by our several clients.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at that! I want to able to add different files to different reducers, and they don't have to be retained in the same node after a particular reduce task is over. Will grid gain help me in achieving this?

Comment: How to integrate GridGain with hadoop, can u give some guidance?